# ASPxGridView deny inserting if exists

Tags: asp.net, devexpress

Is there a setting which will deny inserting row if that row already exists (excluding ID)?

Comment: Are you trying to do this in a control?

Comment: @BojanSkrchevski yes, preferably in a control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to check it in your application, you can use [ASPxGridView.RowInserting](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxGridViewASPxGridView_RowInsertingtopic) event. Just set `e.Cancel` to true if you want to deny row insert. However, this will not prevent direct sql row insert or inserting from some other piece of code in your application.

Answer (score 0):

It’s recommended to control this situation at a datasource level.

Add the required CHECK constraint or INSERT trigger to automatically prevent an inserting operation. This option allows you to handle such situation independent from UI implementation:

http://www.dmxzone.com/go?4615